# Java / Mvn Local Resource not found in .jar Package

Tags: java, maven

I'm tying to add a local Resource (A simple JSON File) to my Maven Project. But when I execute the code, I get the Error:
**java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./resources/test.json (No such file or directory)**

This is the Structure of my Project:

-Router

--src

---main

----java

----resources

-----test.json

--pom.xml

In my pom file I add the json:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>*.json</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

it seems it can't find the resource because in the code when instead of the path I look for

```
this.getClass().getResources("test.json")
```

it returns null. Any suggestions how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't need to add this `<resources>` section to your pom. Maven includes everything from `src/main/resources` by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Class, the path is relative to the package of the class unless you include a leading slash, so if you don't want to use the current package, include a slash like this:

```
this.getClass().getResource("/test.json")
```